# How to match Japanese in spamassassin?

Tags: spam, spamassassin, utf-8

I live in Japan. Recently there has been a lot of spam coming from China with messages written in Chinese. As spamassassin does not contain rules for Chinese, most of those emails pass with low score.

I would like to identify when an email is written in Chinese only. As most of the Japanese kanjis are included in the Chinese range (U+E400 to U+E9FF) one way to identify Japanese is to look at the Hiragana (U+3040 to U+309F) and the Katakana (U+30A0 to U+30FF). If it contains either Hiragana or Katakana I can safely assume is Japanese, otherwise is Chinese.

If I test individual characters, for example: `あ` or `ア` they match correctly, but when I use ranges it doesn't work. This is what we have tried:

```
body    CHINESE       /[\xe4-\xe9]/                 <--- this form seems to work fine
body    JAPANESE      /[\x30-\x31]/                 <--- not sure what is actually matching
body    JAPANESE      /(あ|え)/                      <---- this matches single character just fine
body    JAPANESE      /[あ-ん]/                      <--- doesn't work
body    JAPANESE      /[U+3040-U+30FF]/              <--- doesn't work
body    JAPANESE      /[\xe3\x81\x81-\xe3\x82\x96]/  <--- doesn't work
body    JAPANESE      /[\x{3040}-\x{30FF}]/          <--- doesn't work
```

I really don't know anymore what am I doing. I know some of the above make no sense...

What is the correct way to specify those ranges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to [use Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::TextCat](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_TextCat.html) (language detector)?
IMHO You should consider/evaluate it first.

```
header LANGUAGE_ZH X-Languages =~ /\b(?:zh)\b/
describe LANGUAGE_ZH Chinese language
score LANGUAGE_ZH 1.0

header LANGUAGE_JA X-Languages =~ /\b(?:ja)\b/
describe LANGUAGE_JA Japanese language
score LANGUAGE_JA -0.1
```

You can modify it to match "only one language detected/guessed" or some mixes of languages.

**WARNING:** Make sure the plugin is loaded by your SpamAssassin configuration.
It is configured in `/etc/spamassassin/v310.pre` file on Debian Linux.

Comment: Looks promising! However for some reason is identifying Chinese as Japanese (in my tests)... but that is not your fault. Maybe I'm doing something wrong or its a bug in TextCat. I will keep trying. Thanks!